# How to fix consecutive hyphens did not terminate a comment error?

Tags: html, validation

with the w3 validator (https://validator.w3.org) scan my project but that's found a error.

> Error: Consecutive hyphens did not terminate a comment. -- is not permitted inside a comment, but e.g. - - is.
>   At line 135, column 8
>       ↩

#### all of the that line :

```html
</ul></div></div><!-- end #main-nav -->
```

Why I get this error? How can fix that?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is an old post but I've stumbled upon a similar problem.

The validation error states that `--` are not permitted INSIDE a comment so the following code will throw an error:

```
<!-- Commented resource

Some HTML here

<!-- /comment stops here -->
```

This code will not return a validation error:

```
<!-- Commented resource

Some HTML here

/comments stop here -->
```

This usually happens when you have somenthing with comments and then decide to comment everything and you leave the closing comment intact.

Comment: I had the same problem with `--` in an URL inside a comment. This will throw the error: `<!-- http://test.org/my-url-123--321.html -->`

Answer (score 0):

If your **doctype** is correct, there should be no problem. I've tested

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div><ul><li>li</li></ul></div><!-- end #main-nav -->
</body>

</html>
```

with no warnings and errors. There is something wrong somewhere else. (Maybe `<<`, `>>` or missing closing tag `/>`)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the validator having any problem with such code.

Are you sure it's not spitting-the-dummy over a BEM-esque class name using double hyphens? For example, using class="MyComponent--modifier" will generate your error, even though it is perfectly valid<sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup> According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#characters) a class name cannot *begin* with two consecutive hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the first comment is irrelevant as the example offered does not have two consecutive hyphens embedded in a comment.

My website is replete with consecutive dashes inside comments, as I have long been in the habit of using <!-- ---------- --> as a separator. Fortunately the validator is only *warning* not declaring an *error*. Do I care if my document is not mappable to XML 1.0? I do not. Recommendation to self and others: Ignore this warning and carry on.

```
https://validator.w3.org/ warns me  
"The document is not mappable to XML 1.0 due to two 
consecutive hyphens in a comment. (6)"
```